# Unity - Destroy the DoorController after finishing the task

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, topdown

I have scripted a controller for opening doors in a TopDown-Shooter.

I rotate pivot points around their local Y-Axis to open the door objects. The doors should stay open, so I do not need the Controller and the Controller object anymore. I want to destroy it after finishing its job.

My script looks this:

```
public class DoorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pivotLeftTransform; // the left pivot point
    public Transform pivotRightTransform; // the right pivot point

    int openAngle = 90; // how far should the door open up?
    bool startOpen = false; // start opening?
    float smooth = 2; // smooth rotation

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            startOpen = true; // when the Player triggers, start opening
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (startOpen)
        {
            OpenDoor(pivotLeftTransform, openAngle);
            OpenDoor(pivotRightTransform, -openAngle);

            if (pivotLeftTransform.localRotation.y == openAngle && pivotRightTransform.localRotation.y == -openAngle) // when the doors are rotated, destroy this object
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OpenDoor(Transform pivotTransform, int rotationAngle)
    {
        Quaternion doorRotationOpen = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationAngle, 0); // desired door rotation
        pivotTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(pivotTransform.localRotation, doorRotationOpen, smooth * Time.deltaTime); // rotate the door to the desired rotation
    }
}
```

My Question is, how can I destroy the object. My code

```
if (pivotLeftTransform.localRotation.y == openAngle && pivotRightTransform.localRotation.y == -openAngle)
```

does not seem to work. After having the pivot point rotated to 90 or -90 degrees the statement still stays false. I also tried

```
pivotTransform.rotation.y
```

but it does not work neither. Which rotation do I need to pass in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong in your code:

**1**.Comparing floats

**2**.Using `transform.localRotation` or `transform.rotation` to check for angle.

You can solve this by using `eulerAngles` or `localEulerAngles`. Also for comparing floats, use `>=` instead of `=` as that may never be true.

Replace

```
if (pivotLeftTransform.localRotation.y == openAngle && pivotRightTransform.localRotation.y == -openAngle)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

with

```
if (pivotLeftTransform.localEulerAngles.y >= openAngle && pivotRightTransform.localRotation.y >= -openAngle)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

If you have problem with the answer above you have to troubleshoot it one by one. Separate the `&&` and see which one is failing like this:

```
if (pivotLeftTransform.localEulerAngles.y >= openAngle)
{
    Debug.Log("pivotLeftTransform");
}

if (pivotRightTransform.localRotation.y >= -openAngle)
{
    Debug.Log("pivotRightTransform");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sadly, nothing of these suggestions worked :(

Answer (score -1):

The right way to archieve this is adding a small tolerance value:

```
if (pivotLeftTransform.localEulerAngles.y >= openAngle - 0.1f && pivotRightTransform.localEulerAngles.y <= 360 - openAngle + 0.1f)
```

This may not be code clean but it works for the moment :)